# CakePHP doesn't empty $this->data on redirect

Tags: cakephp

This is the first time I've had this happen to me. I submit the form in one action but instead of clearing $this->data when redirected it actually keeps it. This is the part of the code that fails:

```
if ($this->Order->save($this->data)) {
    $this->redirect("/cart/step_02");
}
```

Comment: sure something I have never experienced myself. can you confirm that it actually loads a new page? using firebug etc?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect certanly causes a new request from the browser,
the only explanation I can think of:

- It is a GET request, you re-submit your data with the redirect.
- It is loaded again in CartController::step_02().
- It is loaded again in CartController(or any superclasse's) beforeXxx() callbacks.

It is unlikely a cake bug, but might be loaded from the persistent class cache,
or some hack causing redirect to fake a requestAction instead.